# NFS - Files on client are not appearing on server

Tags: linux, filesystems, nfs

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [NFS - Files on client are not appearing on server](https://serverfault.com/questions/114272/nfs-files-on-client-are-not-appearing-on-server)

Here my set up:
One NFS Server machine, two NFS client machines.

The client machines write files to the NFS mount, but occasionally, the files don't appear on the NFS Server machine or other client machines.....

I'm absolutely stumped on this one...any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

File doesnt appear even after waiting for some time?
As far as i remember newly created file may not appear immediately but after some time, it should be. NFS client does some caching. 
Check the mount option to prevent the caching (i dont remember).