# NFS clients doesn't see changes in the file-system

Tags: ubuntu, nfs, synchronization

I have a NFS set up with one server and two clients. I'm running into the issue that when I create a file on the server (I'm logged in on the server) I cannot see the new file on the client and visa versa. My problem has somewhat to do with [this](https://serverfault.com/questions/114272/nfs-files-on-client-are-not-appearing-on-server) question but with my problem, the files never show up.

These are the NFS settings on the server (/etc/exports):

```
/share 192.168.43.57/24(rw,no_root_squash,async) 192.168.123.1/24(rw,no_root_squash,async)
```

On my clients, this is how I mount the shares:

```
192.168.43.57:/share     /mnt/share      nfs     rsize=8192,wsize=8192,timeo=14,intr
```

**UPDATE**

I've set up some local virtual machines with the same configuration and the problem does not seem to occur this environment. Not sure where to look to start solving this issue.

Answer (score 2):

I suspect the server exported /share before /share was mounted and clients are seeing the underlying filesystem.

To test (assuming you are on Linux) unmount filesystem on the client, run `exportfs -rv` on server, and then remount on the client. More drastically you could try `exportfs -avu; exportfs -av` rather then the `exportfs -rv`.

Answer (score 1):

Is there some error logs when you mount your share ? when you access it the first time ? Do you have a firewall between/in the machines ? Portmap server is it up ?

Comment: I don't see any errors that I can find (want me to look anywhere specific?). iptables are currently only running on the clients but the problem was already there before iptables was added. Disabling iptables doesn't change the behavior. Portmap on the server is running.

Comment: Portmap is running too on the client (at least on Debian). If you do 'exportfs -v' on the server, all the shares are available ? If not, 'exportfs -rv'